REST API call for Power Automate flows which shows the Standard vs. Premium tier of the flow
I'm currently working on integrating Microsoft Power Automate flows into our application and need some assistance with identifying the tier (Standard vs. Premium) of each flow using REST API calls.
We are utilizing Power Automate to automate various business processes, and we need to differentiate between Standard and Premium flows for compliance and cost management purposes. While I have experience with making REST API calls and working with Power Automate, I'm struggling to find a way to programmatically determine the tier of each flow.
Questions:

Is there a specific REST API endpoint that provides the tier information for Power Automate flows?
If not, is there a workaround or additional steps needed to retrieve this information?
Are there any specific permissions or configurations required to access this tier information via the API?

Any guidance, examples, or references to documentation would be greatly appreciated.
I have gone through the Microsoft Power Automate REST API documentation but couldn't find any specific endpoint that provides the tier information directly. I've experimented with listing flows using the /flows endpoint, but the response does not include any tier-related details.
The example call provided in the documentation is as follows:
GET [Organization URI]/api/data/v9.2/workflows?$filter=category eq 5 and statecode eq 1
&$select=
category,
_createdby_value,
createdon,
description,
ismanaged,
_modifiedby_value,
modifiedon,
name,
_ownerid_value,
statecode,
type,
workflowid,
workflowidunique
&$top=1
Accept: application/json  
OData-MaxVersion: 4.0  
OData-Version: 4.0
Prefer: odata.include-annotations="*"

However, this call does not show the licensing tier (Standard vs. Premium) of the flow.
